# MongoDB not logging to log file

Tags: mongodb

mongodb  at some point stops logging events in the mongodb.log. the mongod process results up.

version Mongodb 4.4 Replica Set ( PSA )

linux operating system CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core).

-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 0 Mar 14 09:48 mongodb.log

Comment: Do you use logrotate or something?

Comment: Hard to believe. What is the last logging entry in the file?

Comment: use the following file to rotate the logs:

/var/log/*.log {
    noolddir
    daily
    rotate 7
    compress
    dateext
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}



why MongoDB does not register in the log file?
what is the solution to adopt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

mongodb gets angry that you changed its file.

You choose two ways for re-logging. first of all, log rotation and secondly db instance bounce.

1. you can use logrotate command. Doc: [LogRotate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/logRotate/)

> db.adminCommand( {logRotate: 1 } )

2. bounce database

> systemctl restart mongodb